# AWS EC2 Windows でのディスク容量監視

Tags: python, aws

AWSのディスク容量監視をしたいのですが下記のようにWEBでサンプルを調達しましたが
CドライブをDドライブに変更するとできません。

具体的には下記のサイトの
中央部分のCドライブの容量を監視したいのですが
Dに変えてもうまくいかない状況でございます。

https://qiita.com/kusokamayarou/items/261efb81d91137ae8321

```
        "Id": "DiskFreePercentC",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
            "CategoryName": "LogicalDisk",
            "CounterName": "% Free Space",
            "InstanceName": "C:",
            "MetricName": "DiskFreePercentC",
            "Unit": "Percent",
            "DimensionName": "InstanceId",
            "DimensionValue": "{instance_id}"
```

どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `WEBでサンプルを調達しましたが` とありますが、監視ツールのサンプルでしょうか？質問文では利用しているツールなどが分からないので、回答は得られなさそうです。質問文編集して具体的に利用しているツールなどを追記してください。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/172072

Comment: すみません、素人でよくわからずで申し訳ございません。下記のサイトに記載されておりました。どうかお願いいたします。

Comment: 「下記のサイト」とはどれでしょうか？ あと、サーバーのディスク構成を教えてください。「CドライブをDドライブに変更するとできません。」と書かれてますがどの様に変更したか手順を教えてください。このへんがわかれば回答できるかもしれません。情報お待ちしてます。

Comment: [別質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52514/3060) にて参照されたサイトの説明がされていますが情報が分散するのは好ましくないので、先に立ったこちらの質問に集約してもらうのがいいのかなと思います。

Answer (score 0):

回答とはちょっと違いますが、SSMエージェントを使ってのログデータ送信はサポートが終了される予定になっているので Cloudwatch エージェントを使ったほうがいいです。

ご参考）https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/monitoring.html

> 重要
>   CloudWatch 統合エージェントによって、ログデータを Amazon CloudWatch Logs に送信するツールとしての SSM エージェントが置き換えられました。SSM エージェントを使用したログデータの送信のサポートは今後廃止されます。ログの取得プロセスに、CloudWatch 統合エージェントをできるだけ早く使い始めることをお勧めします。詳細については、次のトピックを参照してください。 
>       CloudWatch Logs へのログの送信 (CloudWatch エージェント)
>       Windows Server インスタンスのログ収集を CloudWatch エージェント に移行する
>       Amazon CloudWatch User Guideの「CloudWatch エージェントを使用して Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud インスタンスとオンプレミスサーバーからメトリクスとログを収集する」を参照してください。